# When does the inequality hold? $\frac{(6x)^3(2x+1)^2}{2x(2x-1)} < \sqrt[2x]{(6x+1)^{6x+1}}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

For the following inequality, I can see numerically that it will hold at around $x > 1.22$.

\begin{align}
\frac{(6x)^3(2x+1)^2}{2x(2x-1)} < \sqrt[2x]{(6x+1)^{6x+1}}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^+
\end{align}

But is it possible to get the exact $x$? Or is it at least possible to show that this inequality holds for $x \ge 2$ or $x \ge 3$?

Comment: $\left(\frac{(2x+1)^2}{2x(2x-1)}\right)^{2x}$ is bounded, while $(6x+1)^{6x}/(6x)^{6x}$ is going to infinity. Using explicit bounds it should not be hard to prove the inequality for x>2 or 3

Comment: Your inequality is true for any $x>1.005$ and also it's obvious for any $0<x<0.5$.